# Scipy rotate and zoom an image without changing its dimensions

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy

For my neural network I want to augment my training data by adding small random rotations and zooms to my images.  The issue I am having is that scipy is changing the size of my images when it applies the rotations and zooms.  I need to to just clip the edges if part of the image goes out of bounds.  All of my images must be the same size.

```
def loadImageData(img, distort = False):
    c, fn = img
    img = scipy.ndimage.imread(fn, True)

    if distort:
        img = scipy.ndimage.zoom(img, 1 + 0.05 * rnd(), mode = 'constant')
        img = scipy.ndimage.rotate(img, 10 * rnd(), mode = 'constant')
        print(img.shape)

    img = img - np.min(img)
    img = img / np.max(img)
    img = np.reshape(img, (1, *img.shape))

    y = np.zeros(ncats)
    y[c] = 1
    return (img, y)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[`scipy.ndimage.rotate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) accepts a `reshape=` parameter:

> reshape : bool, optional
>
> If `reshape` is true, the output shape is adapted so that the input
>       array is contained completely in the output. Default is True.

So to "clip" the edges you can simply call `scipy.ndimage.rotate(img, ..., reshape=False)`.

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
from scipy.misc import face
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = face()
rot = rotate(img, 30, reshape=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[1].imshow(rot)
```

### [image]

Things are more complicated for [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html).

A naive method would be to `zoom` the entire input array, then use slice indexing and/or zero-padding to make the output the same size as your input. However, in cases where you're increasing the size of the image it's wasteful to interpolate pixels that are only going to get clipped off at the edges anyway.

Instead you could index only the part of the input that will fall within the bounds of the output array before you apply `zoom`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import zoom


def clipped_zoom(img, zoom_factor, **kwargs):

    h, w = img.shape[:2]

    # For multichannel images we don't want to apply the zoom factor to the RGB
    # dimension, so instead we create a tuple of zoom factors, one per array
    # dimension, with 1's for any trailing dimensions after the width and height.
    zoom_tuple = (zoom_factor,) * 2 + (1,) * (img.ndim - 2)

    # Zooming out
    if zoom_factor < 1:

        # Bounding box of the zoomed-out image within the output array
        zh = int(np.round(h * zoom_factor))
        zw = int(np.round(w * zoom_factor))
        top = (h - zh) // 2
        left = (w - zw) // 2

        # Zero-padding
        out = np.zeros_like(img)
        out[top:top+zh, left:left+zw] = zoom(img, zoom_tuple, **kwargs)

    # Zooming in
    elif zoom_factor > 1:

        # Bounding box of the zoomed-in region within the input array
        zh = int(np.round(h / zoom_factor))
        zw = int(np.round(w / zoom_factor))
        top = (h - zh) // 2
        left = (w - zw) // 2

        out = zoom(img[top:top+zh, left:left+zw], zoom_tuple, **kwargs)

        # `out` might still be slightly larger than `img` due to rounding, so
        # trim off any extra pixels at the edges
        trim_top = ((out.shape[0] - h) // 2)
        trim_left = ((out.shape[1] - w) // 2)
        out = out[trim_top:trim_top+h, trim_left:trim_left+w]

    # If zoom_factor == 1, just return the input array
    else:
        out = img
    return out
```

For example:

```
zm1 = clipped_zoom(img, 0.5)
zm2 = clipped_zoom(img, 1.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[1].imshow(zm1)
ax[2].imshow(zm2)
```

[image]

Comment: `scipy.ndimage.zoom` is too slow (no idea why) so your function takes ~500ms for a (480,640) image

Comment: Maybe spline interpolation is causing the slowdown.
Also the zoom center is bottom right corner for zoom-in and center for zoom-out which is confusing. I'd use cv2.resize instead

Comment: @MohamedEzz *"Also the zoom center is bottom right corner for zoom-in and center for zoom-out which is confusing."* - zooming should be about the center of the image, however there was a bug in the way I was computing the bounding box of the zoomed region when `zoom_factor > 1`, which I've now fixed. `clipped_zoom` propagates keyword arguments to `scipy.ndimage.zoom`, so you can pass `order=0` if cubic spline interpolation is too slow. I don't doubt that `cv2.resize` is faster, but OpenCV is a heavy dependency and OP was asking for a scipy-based solution.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Re: runtime, in my answer below i quickly benchmarked order=3 and order=0 and it is still much slower. Agreed that the question is primarily on Scipy but it think there isn't a restriction not to use the better cv2.

Comment: The rounding in `int(np.round(h * zoom_factor))` seems to sometimes cause the resulting image to be 1 pixel smaller than target. The calculation then gets -1 as diff and you get image pixel size 1 for output. Changing to `np.ceil()` instead of `np.round()` seems to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for posting the entire function, very helpful!

Answer (score 14):

I recommend using `cv2.resize` because it is way faster than `scipy.ndimage.zoom`, probably due to support for simpler interpolation methods.

For a 480x640 image :

- `cv2.resize` takes ~2 ms
- `scipy.ndimage.zoom` takes ~500 ms
- `scipy.ndimage.zoom(...,order=0)` takes ~175ms

If you are doing the data augmentation on the fly, this amount of speedup is invaluable because it means more experiments in less time.

Here is a version of `clipped_zoom` using `cv2.resize`

```py
def cv2_clipped_zoom(img, zoom_factor=0):

    """
    Center zoom in/out of the given image and returning an enlarged/shrinked view of 
    the image without changing dimensions
    ------
    Args:
        img : ndarray
            Image array
        zoom_factor : float
            amount of zoom as a ratio [0 to Inf). Default 0.
    ------
    Returns:
        result: ndarray
           numpy ndarray of the same shape of the input img zoomed by the specified factor.          
    """
    if zoom_factor == 0:
        return img


    height, width = img.shape[:2] # It's also the final desired shape
    new_height, new_width = int(height * zoom_factor), int(width * zoom_factor)
    
    ### Crop only the part that will remain in the result (more efficient)
    # Centered bbox of the final desired size in resized (larger/smaller) image coordinates
    y1, x1 = max(0, new_height - height) // 2, max(0, new_width - width) // 2
    y2, x2 = y1 + height, x1 + width
    bbox = np.array([y1,x1,y2,x2])
    # Map back to original image coordinates
    bbox = (bbox / zoom_factor).astype(np.int)
    y1, x1, y2, x2 = bbox
    cropped_img = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    
    # Handle padding when downscaling
    resize_height, resize_width = min(new_height, height), min(new_width, width)
    pad_height1, pad_width1 = (height - resize_height) // 2, (width - resize_width) //2
    pad_height2, pad_width2 = (height - resize_height) - pad_height1, (width - resize_width) - pad_width1
    pad_spec = [(pad_height1, pad_height2), (pad_width1, pad_width2)] + [(0,0)] * (img.ndim - 2)
    
    result = cv2.resize(cropped_img, (resize_width, resize_height))
    result = np.pad(result, pad_spec, mode='constant')
    assert result.shape[0] == height and result.shape[1] == width
    return result
```

Comment: It's a good function. I think that may be better if it can also handle a 0 zoom factor returning th original img. This could be done easily adding a control statement on the zoom parameter at the beginning. I propose an edit if you agree.