# Zoom in an Image using python-numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, image-manipulation

I'm trying to zoom in an image.

```
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import zoom
 import Image 
 zoom_factor = 0.05 # 5% of the original image 
 img = Image.open(filename)
 image_array = misc.fromimage(img)
 zoomed_img = clipped_zoom(image_array, zoom_factor)
 misc.imsave('output.png', zoomed_img)
```

Clipped Zoom Reference:
[Scipy rotate and zoom an image without changing its dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119071/scipy-rotate-and-zoom-an-image-without-changing-its-dimensions)

This doesn't works and throws this error:
    `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape`

Any Help or Suggestions on this
Is there a way to zoom an image given a zoom factor. And what's the problem ?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1443, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "title_apis_proxy.py", line 798, in get
    image, msg = resize_image(image_local_file, aspect_ratio, image_url, scheme, radius, sigma)
  File "title_apis_proxy.py", line 722, in resize_image
    z = clipped_zoom(face, 0.5, order=0)
  File "title_apis_proxy.py", line 745, in clipped_zoom
    out[top:top+zh, left:left+zw] = zoom(img, zoom_factor, **kwargs)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (963,1291,2) into shape (963,1291,3)
```

Comment: I can imagine there is a problem with the basic data-format of the image. Why not read in the image with [scipy's functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html#scipy.ndimage.imread) (which is also using PIL; but it may be better suited handling some assumptions about the data-structure)? And what is ```clipped_zoom```? You are only importing zoom, which has just one function ```zoom``` in scipy 0.18.0.

Comment: I took help from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119071/scipy-rotate-and-zoom-an-image-without-changing-its-dimensions 
this contains the clipped_zoom function

Comment: Well... this does not make it easier to debug. If you really want some help  here, you should give us all the information. The ```clipped_zoom``` thing, how should we know? Also... you are posting only part of the error (it probably shows you, which reshape operation/numpy-operation is breaking -> where in code)

Comment: Added traceback, is that helpful ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `clipped_zoom` function you're using from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37121993/1461210) was written for single-channel images only.

At the moment it's applying the same zoom factor to the "color" dimension as well as the width and height dimensions of your input array. The `ValueError` occurs because the the `out` array is initialized to the same number of channels as the input, but the result of `zoom` has fewer channels because of the zoom factor.

To make it work for multichannel images you could either pass each color channel separately to `clipped_zoom` and concatenate the results, or you could pass a tuple rather than a scalar as the `zoom_factor` argument to `scipy.ndimage.zoom`.

I've updated my previous answer using the latter approach, so that it will now work for multichannel images as well as monochrome.

Comment: Great it works fine, but sometimes it shows a warning `serWarning: From scipy 0.13.0, the output shape of zoom() is calculated with round() instead of int() - for these inputs the size of the returned array has changed.
  "the returned array has changed.", UserWarning)` . Should I ignore this ?

Comment: You should be fine, since my code also uses `np.round` to compute the dimensions of the output. By the way, scipy 0.13.0 came out ~3 years ago, so you might consider updating.