# problem with the 2d interpolation method using scipy.ndimage.zoom

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing

I have an image which is in gray scale.
I wanted to upsamle the image, so I used the following code,

```
img = cv2.imread('unnamed.jpg')
img_1 = scipy.ndimage.zoom(img,3, order=1)
print(img.shape, img_1.shape)
```

and the output is

```
(187, 250, 3) (561, 750, 9)
```

For some reason, I cannot use plt.imshow(img_1) as it gives error,

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (561, 750, 9) for image data
```

I'd appreciate it if somebody could help me with it.

Comment: Since you're using OpenCV, this is an option: `img_1 = cv2.resize(img, (width * 3, height * 3), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)`

Otherwise see this post which describes how to avoid operating on the RGB channel:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119071/scipy-rotate-and-zoom-an-image-without-changing-its-dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your image has 3 channels, which means it is not in grayscale. So, either convert it to grayscale first, and apply `zoom`, or, in case you want to keep the image in color mode, don't apply `zoom` on the image channels, because it does not make much sense.

```
# 1st option returns grayscale image
img = cv2.imread('unnamed.jpg',0) #  returns grayscale image
img_1 = scipy.ndimage.zoom(img,3, order=1)

# 2nd option returns BGR image
img = cv2.imread('unnamed.jpg',1) #  returns RGB image
img_1 = scipy.ndimage.zoom(img,[3,3,1], order=1) # zoom should contain one value for each axis.
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I mistook the photo to be gray scaled, and I never realized about channels before. the second option worked for me.  :) :)