# Image Zoom Using SciPy - wrong dimensions

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, zooming

The code from answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119071/scipy-rotate-and-zoom-an-image-without-changing-its-dimensions/37121993#37121993) question produces an error for some values of zoom factor.

As mentioned in comments by @kg_sYy, "*The rounding in `int(np.round(h * zoom_factor))` seems to sometimes cause the resulting image to be 1 pixel smaller than target. The calculation then gets -1 as diff and you get image pixel size 1 for output. Changing to `np.ceil()` instead of `np.round()` seems to fix it.*"
However, changing to `np.ceil()` does not fix the error.

As an example, `zoom_factor = 1.1317` and image `shape (331, 331, 3)` result in `zoomed_img` being one pixel in size.

What other rounding function could fix the problem and why does it occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why it becomes a single pixel

The code you have linked in question makes the assumption that:

> `out` might still be slightly larger than `img` due to rounding, so trim off any extra pixels at the edges

And then proceeds to do trimming without checking anything. The zoomed image becomes 1 pixel whenever `out` is actually smaller than `img` (due to bad rounding, as the comment mentions). Then these following calculations fail:

```
trim_top = ((out.shape[0] - h) // 2)
trim_left = ((out.shape[1] - w) // 2)
```

Since the new image is actually smaller than `(h, w)`, the `trim_top` and `trim_left` are actually negative numbers (-1, empirically).

So the final trim is actually:

```
out = out[-1: h - 1, -1: w - 1]
```

This is nothing but the bottom right pixel at [-1, -1].

#### How to fix

- Ensure that `out` is equal or greater than `img`. Using `ceil()` *should* handle this. (See if you can find any image size and zoom factor for which `out` is still smaller than `img`.)
- Check whether `out` is actually greater than `img` before trying to trim it.
- Handle a possible round off when doing the trim.

```
def clipped_zoom(img, zoom_factor, **kwargs):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]

    zoom_tuple = (zoom_factor,) * 2 + (1,) * (img.ndim - 2)

    # Zooming out
    if zoom_factor < 1:

        # Bounding box of the zoomed-out image within the output array
        zh = int(np.round(h * zoom_factor))
        zw = int(np.round(w * zoom_factor))
        top = (h - zh) // 2
        left = (w - zw) // 2

        # Zero-padding
        out = np.zeros_like(img)
        out[top:top+zh, left:left+zw] = zoom(img, zoom_tuple, **kwargs)

    # Zooming in
    elif zoom_factor > 1:

        # Bounding box of the zoomed-in region within the input array
        zh = int(np.ceil(h / zoom_factor))
        zw = int(np.ceil(w / zoom_factor))

        top = (h - zh) // 2
        left = (w - zw) // 2

        out = zoom(img[top: top + zh, left: left + zw], zoom_tuple, **kwargs)

        # >>> Check out against img before trying to trim
        # >>> trim safely, accounting for rounding

        if out.shape[0] > h:
            h_diff = out.shape[0] - h
            trim_top = h_diff // 2
            trim_bottom = h_diff - trim_top
            out = out[trim_top: out.shape[0] - trim_bottom, :]

        if out.shape[1] > w:
            w_diff = out.shape[1] - w
            trim_left = w_diff // 2
            trim_right = w_diff - trim_left
            out = out[:, trim_left: out.shape[1] - trim_right]     

    # If zoom_factor == 1, just return the input array
    else:
        out = img
    return out
```